# Trouble selecting dropdown menu with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying access a page which requires me to select an option from a drop down menu.

When i run my code atm, I get an error where it says it was unable to locate the drop down element by id. I do not know how to remedy this situation, as I am copying and pasting the elements id.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://webapp.northampton.edu/coursesearch/default.aspx')
time.sleep(1)
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id('pg0_V_ddlTerm')
select_box = Select(dropdown)
time.sleep(1)
select_box.select_by_value('2015;S2')
```

I also tried selecting by name, but that also proved fruitless. 
Once I select the dropdown I am attempting to select the option S2 2015.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: I put in the time.sleep because I thought perhaps the website wasn't fully loaded by the time is was trying to select the drop down.

Comment: .select_by_value() returns an element right?  You're not capturing that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select *element is inside an iframe*, [switch to it](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_frame):

```
driver.switch_to.frame("cSearch")

dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id('pg0_V_ddlTerm')
select_box = Select(dropdown)
select_box.select_by_value('2015;S2')
```

Comment: whats the `time.sleep` for?

Comment: @nilesh what `time.sleep`? ;)

Comment: This worked thanks! If you don't mind, could you elaborate on exactly what frame is and why I have to switch to it?

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in using an [action chain](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains). From the docs:

> ActionChains are a way to automate low level interactions such as mouse movements, mouse button actions, key press, and context menu interactions.

Example:

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id('pg0_V_ddlTerm')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(dropdown)
actions.click(dropdown)
select_box = Select(dropdown)
action.move_to_element(select_box.select_by_value('2015;S2'))
action.click(select_box)
actions.perform()
```